# How to use ibus for user input in BGE

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

I am using BGUI for creating text field inside BGE. I cold enter English. I need to enter some other language. I could enter that language using ibus, but not able inside Blender (when run). Is it possible to enter that language inside Blender? Whether ibus could be used? or is there any other option?

Comment: I not sure if I fully understand your problem, but there is a [bug report](https://developer.blender.org/T40179) for entering Chinese text in a running game and an [forum thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?336196-How-to-input-Chinese-in-a-game-Or-how-to-apply-the-system-input-method-in-game). If this is the same as your problem, then it is a bug. Otherwise it would help if you give some more information.

Comment: @TobiMarg Ya now it seems like a bug. Thanks for the pointers